# Best way to compare ReadOnlyMemory<T> instances?

Tags: c#

The `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` provide `Equal(other)` method but no `CompareTo(other)`. I wonder if there a more efficient way to implement `IComparable<ReadOnlyMemory<T>>` other than a loop and compare each element. In my case `T` is either `char` or `byte`.

Comment: What you mean as "compare" pieces of memory? You should define how to do it, first.

Comment: @MarioVernari By compare in this case I mean semantics such as in IComparable<T> used for sorting and ordering

Answer (score 4):

There does not appear to be a native method of comparing ReadOnlyMemory instances. There are however native methods for ReadOnlySpan, which can be accessed by using the ReadOnlyMemory's .Span property:

```cs
ReadOnlyMemory<T> One = ...;
ReadOnlyMemory<T> Two = ...;

bool ContentsEqual = One.Span.SequenceEqual(Two.Span);
int Comparison = One.Span.SequenceCompareTo(Two.Span);
```

Enjoy :)