# Two equivalent spans failing equality check

Tags: c#

I have come across this bizarre behavior where two equivalent `IReadOnlySpan<Char>` are failing equality check, debugging seems to show that both are identical yet `operator==` returns `false`

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<Char> s1 = "true false"[0..4];
ReadOnlySpan<Char> s2 = "true";

Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2);
```

Comment: [Msdn ReadOnlySpan<T>.Equality Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1.op_equality?view=net-5.0#remarks) : In the remark session _"This tests if two ReadOnlySpan<T> instances point to the same starting memory location, and have the same Length values. This does not compare the contents of two ReadOnlySpan<T> instances."_

Comment: @DragandDrop aha, I totally missed that, is there a built-in way to compare the contents without converting it to string?

Comment: I will say sequence equals maybe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010205/best-way-to-compare-readonlymemoryt-instances , Or [MemoryExtensions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions?view=net-7.0) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289559/spanchar-and-string-equality

Comment: @DragandDrop sweet thanks you may submit this as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: And for reference a bit of performance numbers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864673/c-sharp-readonlyspanchar-vs-substring-for-string-dissection. 
For answers I any of those link cover 100% of your question , choose it as dupe. If the comment "how to compare" is part of the question , edit it in. and check if it's not a dupe. Anyone can take the mats an redact an answer. just wanted to give a quick feed back with enought source